# decodeObjectForKey: array in Custom object returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nscoding

I want to store array of custom object. So I have tried encode and decode. but its not working

Please check my code.

```
    - (IBAction)saveFile{
    NSLog(@"%@",self.drawingView.pathArray);
      NSData *arrayData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self.drawingView];
    [arrayData writeToFile:[DOCUMENTPATH stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"1.plist"] atomically:YES];
}
```

Console O/P

```
 (
    "<ACEDrawingPenTool: 0x8b48d80;>",
    "<ACEDrawingPenTool: 0xa225530;>"
)
```

Now I m encoding array with this

```
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:self.pathArray forKey:@"array"];
}
```

After this when I try to get object

```
 - (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
        self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        self.pathArray = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"array"];
        NSLog(@"%@",self.pathArray);  // returns nil
        [self configure];
    }
    return self;
}
```

decodeObjectForKey returns nil

Comment: Does adding `[super encodeWithCoder:encoder]` to your `encodeWithCoder:` method help?

Comment: have you checked the contents of the generated file? does it look sensible?

Comment: @robmayoff i have written that file but not work,, yes its save